# how to make my own fckeditor plugin

Tags: plugins, fckeditor

I'm using fckeditor in my blog and I want to make my own plugin or button.
I need a button and when press it writes < !--kamore-->.
But I can't find any document or sample.

Comment: Sorry I didn't have time to read through and provide a proper answer but I found this: http://cksource.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=7808 They seem to have been having the same issue and managed to resolve it. If it helps please post back your code here and answer your own question as I would be interested to see how its done

Comment: This was very old question but anyway. Thanks alot. I'm gonna try it asap. Because after I couldn't find a solution I stopped searching.